# How to Theme a web site using Jquery UI? any tutorials and Demos?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can you provide me links and resources for jquery UI themed websites or home pages and tutotirals on how to theme a page using Jquery UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the jQuery UI CSS Framework/Theming API here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API

Basically it's a bunch of classes you can use to style your layout consistently, many plugins use these same classes, the link above lists most of the classes there (assured not to change) and descriptions of each. Now to customize any theme, the UI team provides [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).  You can also use ThemeRoller to quickly get the classes of icons and such, just hover over them to see what class they are.

When you're designing though and want to tweak your look once you start using classes, you can use the [ThemeRoller developer tool](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/) (bookmarklet, only works in Firefox) to see live changes to *your* page (instead of the ThemeRoller demo page).

Answer (score 0):

See [JQuery UI Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

and [JQuery Theme Roller](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/Themeroller)